# Вставка значений в select, option

Tags: php, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть txt файл. Файл имеет данные - html теги (`<p>Текст</p><a>Ссылка</a>`).
Так же есть select на сайте:

```
<select>
<option>...</option>
<option>...</option>
<option>...</option>
<option>...</option>
</select>
```

Нужно что бы тэги из файла заносились в select
Вот так:

```
<select>
<option><p>Текст</p></option>
<option><a>Ссылка</a></option>
</select>
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Пример файла в студию

Comment: @EatMyDust <p>Текст</p><a>Ссылка</a>

Answer (score 0):

Как то так (если я Вас правильно понял):

```
//Получаем содержимое файла в виде массива
$content = file('text.txt');

//Перебираем все элементы массива в цикле
foreach ($content as $string) {
    $string = explode("<a>", $string);
    echo '<option>' . $string[0] . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
//open file
$file = file("1.txt");

//init array
$arOptions = array();

//Read the file row by row
foreach($file as $key => $row)
{
    //get text
    preg_match("#<p>(.*)</p>#", $row, $text);
    //get links
    preg_match("#<a>(.*)</a>#", $row, $link);

    //put data to array
    $arOptions[$key]['text'] = $text[1];
    $arOptions[$key]['link'] = $link[1];

}
?>
<select>
    <? foreach($arOptions as $row): ?>
        <option><?=$row['text'];?></option>
        <option><?=$row['link'];?></option>
    <? endforeach; ?>
</select>
```